# Can't present viewcontroller through URL scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to present a viewcontroller from `AppDelegate` with an URL Scheme. Inside the code for the URL scheme, I have the following code to present the `UIViewController`:

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

UIStoryboard *storyboard;

if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"])
{
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
} else if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"])
{
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard-iPad" bundle:nil];
}

MainVC *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
viewController.number = number;
viewController.url = YES;

UIViewController *activeController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
if ([activeController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    activeController = [(UINavigationController*) activeController visibleViewController];
}
[activeController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

When the app is first launched through the url scheme, this works fine. However, when the app is running in the background and it's launched through an url, it doesn't work. What's causing this?

Comment: Is this in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said that it works when the first run, I suppose it's because your root view controller is a navigation controller which seems you need.

But let's say that during using application you have few queue of navigations and presentation new view controllers. So then when you enter to background from application the top view controller it's not the root that you are thinking as an `activeController`.

So in your code the line:

```
UIViewController *activeController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

just means that you will access to the root (firs view controller in your queue), but you then need last one view controller in case if you had some presentation or pushes when using app.

So here are two approaches as I think:

- Find top view controller and make presentation from it.
- Close a queu/stack of controllers (like dismiss it or pop back) and present your MainVC from the point you need.

So you should think about your controllers as about 
for EXAMPLE stack of books. So if your stack count of the books equal to 10 and you want to present new book from 6th book you need to drop 4 top books before and then place new book over. Or you just can find 10th book and put 11 book over 10 book (which is seems your MainVC). Maybe it's rough example but you should to find point from where it's possible to present new view controller or if it's already presented then you need to remove presented/pushed view controller from a queue.

Hope it help you.